# Haskell newbie on understanding function composition

Tags: haskell

I've been reviewing this code fragment from the Haskell Hierarchical library.
I can follow most of the fragments of the code below, but the "." (function composition) behavior in this case has thrown me because of what I expect the arguments to be for foldr, specifically: foldr f z list.  I see parseLine as f, z as M.empty, lines as list.  So I expect my confusion is around the behavior of the function composition and the where clause.  Any assistance in understanding this function would be much appreciated as I try and make sense out of Haskell.

```
 -- Parse the file we've just read in, by converting it to a list of lines,
 -- then folding down this list, starting with an empty map and adding the
 -- username and password for each line at each stage.
  parseMap :: String -> PassDB
  parseMap = foldr parseLine M.empty . lines
     where parseLine ln map = 
             let [un, pw] = words ln
             in M.insert un pw map
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to parse this expression as `(foldr parseLine M.empty) . (lines)`. So you are right that `parseLine` and `M.empty` are the first and second argument to `foldr` here. However, `lines` is not an argument to `foldr`.

So `foldr` is still missing one argument, that is, `foldr parseLine M.empty` is a function of type `[String] -> PassDB`. And `lines` is also missing one argument, it is a function from `String -> [String]`. And that's the two functions that the `.` is composing here. So together we get a function of type `String -> PassDB`.

Note that the argument is still missing, so `parseMap` is a function. Just as its type annotation says.

Comment: A slight correction: `foldr parseLine M.empty` has type `[a] -> PassDB`, since `a` hasn't been bound to anything yet.

Comment: @chepner: Wouldn't `a` be fixed anyway by the type of `parseLine`, which is presumably `String -> PassDB -> PassDB`?

Comment: Good point. `words :: String -> [String]` implies `ln :: String`, `un :: String`, and `map ::String`, which fixes the type of `parseLine` and QED.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm closer to understanding this.  Now, how does the arguments to parseLine in the where clause line up?  ln is the line for words and map is the accumulator of foldr, but the argument order seems wrong.

Comment: Check the type of `foldr` to see that the argument order is not wrong after all.

Comment: Yep, I follow the composition of foldr and lines now, but my next point of confusion is the where clause and how the arguments of parseLine, specifically ln map, work with the composed function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If you can't figure it out, maybe you should ask a new question?

Comment: Yes, I understand now.  The type of foldr, specifically for the function arguments, resolved my confusion about argument order for the where clause.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First I should say that in Haskell, *all functions take one argument*. That's called [currying](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#curried-functions) and that is what allows the syntax you posted.

Then, this syntax is an instance of [pointfree](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree) style. You can read it in a pointful style as follows:

```
parseMap :: String -> PassDB
parseMap    s       = foldr parseLine M.empty . lines $ s
  where parseLine ln map = 
        let [un, pw] = words ln
        in M.insert un pw map
```

Going from the above form to the form you posted is called performing an [eta-reduction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Eta_conversion).

You can be warned by smart editors that integrate [hlint](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/hlint/) (such as emacs with [haskell-mode](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode))  when you can perform eta-reduction.

When you've understood all that, understanding the function composition is just realizing that the input string will first be given as input to `lines`, that function will turn the string into a list, and then the resulting list will be given to `foldr`.